# Node server does not start when using yarn workspaces

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, rollup, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to use Yarn Workspaces to slit up my React. This is my folder structure.

React

- packages

  - commonComponents

    - package.json
  - app 1

    - package.json
  - app 2

    - package.json

The `commonComponents` folder is installed into the node_modules of `app 1` and `app 2`.

While my builds succeed, I'm not able to startup my node server.  The following error is thrown:

[image: Current syntax error]

I assume that babel doesn't transpile correctly. Any help?

Comment: Your assumption is right. It’s related to babel. Make sure you set babel preset in .babelrc file

Comment: Hi Hemadri Dasari, I've already set my preset into the .babelrc file, but it isn't working. Hi Hemadri Dasari, I've already set my preset into the .babelrc file, but it isn't working.                                                                                                             
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "loose": true,
      "targets": {
        "node": "current",
        "browsers": ["last 4 versions"]
      }
    }],
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}